# convolution product of $\sin(x)$ and $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: integration, convolution

I am supposed to find the convolution product of the two functions $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = e^{-x^2}$.

I tried different approaches (for example integrating by parts or calculating the Fourier transforms of the functions in order to multiply and back-transform it then), but I always end up with results that are “blowing up”.
I am not sure whether I am making a mistake in those approaches or if there might be some kind of easier trick to solve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You sure about `exp(-x^2)`?

Comment: Yes, at least that is what is written in the exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maple says
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\!\sin \left( x \right)\, {{\rm e}^{- \left( y-
x \right) ^{2}}}\,{\rm d}x
=\sqrt{\pi}\, e^{-1/4}\sin y 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do you get there?

Comment: @lh1509 Substitute $x-y=u$, use addition formula for sine, use odd-even property of integrals and then use differentiation under the integral sign to solve the final integral.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari. Completing the square makes it shorter but you solution is nice

Comment: Thank you! This worked out now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\,\sin \left( x \right)\, {{\rm e}^{- \left( y-
x \right) ^{2}}}\,dx=\Im\int e^{i x-(x-y)^2}\,dx$$
$$(x-y)^2-ix=\left(x-y-\frac{i}{2}\right)^2-i y+\frac{1}{4}$$ Let $x=t+y+\frac{i}{2}$ to make
$$I=\Im\Bigg[ e^{i y-\frac 14}\int e^{-t^2}\,dt\Bigg]=\frac{ \sin (y)}{\sqrt[4]{e}}\int e^{-t^2}\,dt$$